# What is the exact difference between linearly separable and non-linearly separable data points?

Tags: regression, data-visualization, separation

Does the separating boundary of a given set of points *have* to be a straight line (or a flat hyperplane)?

The image below seems to be clearly linearly separable.

[image]

The other one here (the classic XOR) is certainly non-linearly separable.
[image]

But how about these two?

[image]
[image]

Both of them seems to be separable by a single line, though not straight. Are they linearly separable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. In the coordinate systems you've chosen, they are not linearly separable. The classes of data must be separable by a hyperplane, that is, a boundary that takes the form of $w_1x_1 + w_2x_2 + ... + w_px_p = C$. If you can find a coordinate system where this is true, then it will be linearly separable in the new coordinate system but not necessarily in the old.

Comment: In your example with blue and green points, you can introduce a center and then shift to polar coordinates. It will be linearly separable in the polar coordinates!

Comment: The definitions of "linearly separable" with which I am familiar--see, for instance, the Wikipedia article on the subject--do not admit the possibility of a change of coordinates.  You have to use the coordinates you are given.  According to your definition, *all* the examples in the question are "linearly separable."  In fact, it's not difficult to show that according to your definition all finite groups of non-overlapping points are "linearly separable."

Comment: I agree. That's why I answered "No".  I then reasoned if you can find a basis such that a hyperplane works, then it will be linearly separable in that new basis.  I should have wrote: "If you can find a coordinate system where this is true, then it will be linearly separable in the new coordinate system but not the old.

Comment: It's a lot clearer to me now. Thanks Matt. Great insight @kjetilbhalvorsen! I never looked at that angle before.

Comment: @whuber: So the separability should only be accounted without any coordinate transformation, right? Thanks for the added clarity.

Comment: @Matt We welcome edits to answers to improve them.  To illustrate, I have inserted the sentence from your comment into the answer.  Feel free to keep adding to or improving on your answer (+1).